# Pandas read_sql() returns not the whole values, reduces the size

Tags: python, sql, pandas

I am fetching a table from a database with read_sql()

```
table = pd.read_sql('SELECT * FROM {}'.format(table), con=engine)
```

But in the result, some characters in rows are substituted by 3 dots (...).

Example:

```
A  B     C
1  name  example_name...
2  city  example_city...
```

If I explicitly populate a df with the reduced values, it is ok.

Example:

```
A  B     C
1  name  example_name_Name1
2  city  example_city_Name2
```

I googled but haven't found an answer why it happens like this.

Comment: it's just a shortened presentation of "long" values

Comment: Can you not try print(table.to_string()) to see the un-shortened version?

Comment: I need to pass it as a parameter, not to see it